# what is a danger of leaving constraints errors in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, constraints

I had to remove few thousands records from a table which had many FK constraints.
I stopped constraints enforcement in for all tables and deleted the records plus fixed some 
obvious constraints which DBCC check showed me and then I have enabled back constraints.
After that DBCC check still shows some errors unfortunately, but at this point I have no time
to search why. My question is then like in title maybe stupid but what can happen if I leave database for a while with constraints errors? Will the app which uses this DB be affected?
Can I deffer fixing the constraints?  (I use SQL Server 2008)
thanks

Comment: You mean you re enabled the constraints with the nocheck option? Any updates to the offending rows will fail even if they don't touch the column value at fault. Also whilst untrusted the query optimiser won't use them to potentially simplify queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have data that is lacking integrity (has some invalid information). This will not make the database crash or produce errors, but how the application will react to this depends entirely on the application. You might see some error pages, or even worse, the invalid data will propagate to produce even more invalid data or actions (that could be even harder to track down and fix afterwards).

The point of these constraints is to make the database validate (or reject) the data, so that the application can rely on certain invalid patterns not occurring in the data. Many applications are built to not use these assurances and handle data integrity themselves, but if your application did depend on them, and then you pull them out from under it, that sounds a bit dangerous.

Comment: thanks, I was afraid about this as well so I spent few more hours and got all constraints resolved.